# Java : method reference of an arbitrary object

Tags: java

Given the following code (copied out of context to keep things simple)
It works fine, and enables OAuth2 JWT token validation.

```
...
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer;
...
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt);
}
...
```

I have a hard time understanding the `OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt` method reference

`httpConfig.oauth2ResourceServer` expects an `Customizer` as input. The `Customizer` is a functionnal interface that defines one instance method which is `void customize(T t)`.

The `jwt` instance method of `OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer` returns an object of type `OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer.JwtConfigurer`, which does not define the `void customize(T t)` method.

How can it comply with the `Customizer` interface?

Also, I don't understand which instance of `OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer` will be used to call the 'jwt()' method.

The basic Java article does not help me. (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)

I am familiar with Lambdas and method references, but this one I don't get.

Comment: If the lambda expects a void, then it's _specifically_ permissible to supply a method reference that returns any value, and the value is discarded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can it comply with the `Customizer` interface?

When a method reference implements a functional interface, the parameters and the return type have to comply (be compatible), not the method name.

Consistent with how a lambda expression has to have parameters and a return type that is compatible with the functional method, but the method name isn't given anywhere.

> Also, I don't understand which instance of `OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer` will be used to call the `jwt()` method.

In the link you provided, see the section named "[Reference to an Instance Method of an Arbitrary Object of a Particular Type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html#type)".

Since your method reference is [`OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.5.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/oauth2/server/resource/OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer.html#jwt--), which is a no-arg instance method, the `t` parameter of the [`customize(T t)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.5.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/security/config/Customizer.html#customize-T-) method becomes the `this` value of the `jwt()` call.

It is basically the same as this lambda expression:

```java
http.oauth2ResourceServer(t -> t.jwt());
```

Which is equivalent to this anonymous class:

```java
http.oauth2ResourceServer(new Customizer<OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer<HttpSecurity>>() {
    @Override
    public void customize(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer<HttpSecurity> t) {
        t.jwt();
    }
});
```